# Listings with keywords count as keyword stuffing / spamming?

Tags: seo, google, keyword-stuffing

I'm managing some "Hotel-Booking" projects where I get large lists with hotels.

Let's say I want my main keywords to be "Foo-Town hotels" and I've around 180 hotels in that city.

I already cut this list to 20 hotels by loading the other asynchronous (via Ajax with jQuery).

But there are now like 20 hotels with a name like "My-New-**Hotel**brand **Foo-Town** **Hotel**", the address (Foo-Street 2, 12345 **Foo-Town**) and a 150 words description which includes the city name and the keyword "hotel".

Does Google realizes that this list (its in a HTML unsorted list) is from a database or do I need to prevent Google from index the hotel list, and if yes, how I do it the best?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get your page ranked, is to have relevant information showing on the page when it first loads, and that the content pertains to the search phrase you're targeting. If you're worried about a piece of content on a particular page, you will have to load it well after the page has finished loading the first time, so the negative content won't get indexed.

Try looking at your competitors and see what their pages show coming from the SERPs. This will help you understand if you're going after a realistic target phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong questions.   The questions you should be asking are:

- Is this list of hotels useful for users?
- Is a list format what users expect to see?
- Can my users do something with this list of hotels that they can't do on any other site? (or even do something better, more easily, or cheaper)
- Do I have content to show that isn't available on other websites?

If users like your site, users find your site more useful than your competitors, and you have original content, your site will do fine.    There is nothing inherently spammy about keywords that get reused in a list.

If your site isn't original, doesn't work better than your competitors, or doesn't provide added value to your users, then the large amount of keyword repetition isn't going to do you any favors.   Even then though, it would be the least of your worries.